# Docker as replacement for standalone multihost webserver

Tags: webserver, docker

I'm thinking about build system for my web server based on docker probably on CoreOS.
Now I have two apache webservers primary and fallback which are in sync.

I want to move my actual webserver to container and build new one with new php and nginx for new projects.

I want to store all applications data and code outside of container in mounted folder as volume. But not sure if it's good approach. Mostly it's because of need to keep current deploy with jenkins, and all code is also in git repository.

Is there some best practice, how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting into the "experimental" side of devops.  There's nothing wrong with that, but it is a bit like the wild west.  If you use Docker, Vagrant, etc, make sure you're using OO best practices.  And just pick a sensible approach.